# How to be able to "require" a config file using browserify but not have this file included in the bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I have an angular application which uses browserify to modularise the Javascript components.

I have a config file which holds environment specific information which I also have as a module, so I can require it to get access to this information. For example another module can just `var config = require("./config)` and then use this config object to access the configuration information

However I do not want this file to be added to the bundle.js since I want it to be easily editable and no compilation to be required if the information inside it is changed.

Is there a way I can still access it using *require* but not have it added to the bundle?

Answer (score -1):

You can parse a json file and read its contents with this: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: This is for using nodeJs to read a file from the file system. I do not think it is relevant to an angular web application